# How can I abbreviate the word "Assessor"?

Tags: abbreviations

I need to reduce the character count on a document I am preparing and the word "Assessor" appears many times. What would be an appropriate abbreviation for this word?

Answer (score 2):

[allacronyms.com/ASR./Assessor](https://www.allacronyms.com/ASR./Assessor) : "asr." means *assessor*

---

ASSRS - ASSESSORS –[skagitcounty.net](http://www.skagitcounty.net/assessor/html/abreviations.htm)

Comment: This answer is "barely more than a link to an external site" ([help]) and has been flagged as low quality because of its length and content.